# DbContextOptionsBuilder is not working as expected at ASP.NET Core 6 project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I configure my Startup file as below,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreContext>();
  dbContextOptions.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

  if (_env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    dbContextOptions.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
  }

  services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x => x = dbContextOptions);

  services.AddApplicationServices(_env, _config);
  services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles));
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();
  services.AddCors();
}
```

the app gives me the below error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

When I changed this line

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x => x = dbContextOptions);
```

to

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

then it is working. But what am I missing, why doesn't work first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is you are assigning parameter passed into an action you are creating by `x => x = dbContextOptions`, which is in the beginning reference to existing instance of options, but it would’t change reference outside of the action. Just inside the action the reference is changed.

Try this.

```
string original = "original";

Action<string> action = x => x = "new";

action(original);

Console.WriteLine(original); // Output: original
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: you are right, thanks